# Vtable implementation in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++

Iam unable to figure out the patten on how vtables are created for multiple inheritance. Please look at following code.

```
// Iam just providing pseudocode model
class A{
  public:
         Vptr[];    // create function pointer 
         virtual void run(){}
         A(){
             this->Vptr[0] = &A::run; // push virtual function address
         }
}

class B{
  public:
         Vptr[];   // create function pointer
         virtual void sleep(){}
         B(){
             this->Vptr[0] = &B::sleep; // push virtual function address
         }
}

class C : public A, public B{
  public: 
         virtual void run(){}
         virtual void eat(){}
          C(){
             this->A::Vptr[0] = &C::run; // update function address since overrided

             // the question is onto which Vptr does eat() entry is stored?
             // this->A::Vptr[1] = &C::eat() OR this->B::Vptr[1] = &C::eat()
          } 
}
```

In the case of single inheritance level, it keeps adding the virtual function entries to the same `VPTR` at the end but in the multiple inheritance how does it decide? because it has 2 Vptrs

Comment: I recommend you refrain from the `this->` syntax; address the methods and members directly (saves typing time).  You only need the `this->` syntax to distinguish between method parameters and data members *that have the same name*.

Comment: What is the type for `Vptr`?

Comment: I believe that since there is no overloading or overriding of the `run` and `eat` methods that the compiler could optimize and not use a virtual function table.

Comment: Use the C++11 *override* keyword and it probably will become more obvious.  The compiler has no trouble figuring out that it must override A::run(), B doesn't have one.  When it does have one then the trouble starts.

Comment: You need to state an ABI. C++ itself has no notion of virtual tables; it's an implementation detail!

Comment: The C++ language standard doesn't use the word vtable. Your implementation may or may not be using vtables today (in a different way from my implementation, or from your implementation tomorrow). Why would you need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your code is actually pseudo-C++.

But your code is wrong, because in C++ the vtable is per-class, not per-instance. And each instance holds a pointer to the vtable of its class.

So it would be something like (pseudo-C++, of course);

```
fn_t A::VTable[] = { &A::run };
fn_t B::VTable[] = { &B::sleep };
fn_t C::VTable[] = { &C::run, &C::eat };

A::A()
{
    A::VPtr = A::VTable;
}
B::B()
{
    B::VPtr = B::VTable;
}
C::C()
{
    A::VPtr = C::VTable;
    B::VPtr = B::VTable;
}
```

As you can see, `C` has two VTables, one inherited from `A` and one from `B`. The first one is extended with all the new virtual functions of `C`.

If `C` were to override `sleep()`, then it would build a new VTable:

```
fn_t C::VTableB[] = { &C::sleep };

C::C()
{
    A::VPtr = C::VTable;
    B::VPtr = C::VTableB;
}
```

Comment: Is a virtual table necessary in this example?  The methods for `class A` and `class B` are unique, so the compiler could generate code that accesses the methods in `class A` and `class B` from `class C` as if they were declared in `class C`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I think they are. First, you cannot be sure there will not be subclasses of `C`. Second, this is multiple inheritance, so you may need to do some `this` adjustments in virtual calls, so you will need some vtable thunks.